# canvas button content disappears

Tags: wpf, canvas, caliburn, contentpresenter

I've got some weird behavior in a project i'm working on.

[image: weird bug]

Code in question:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="DeleteThruster($dataContext)" ToolTip="Delete">
    <Button.Content>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource appbar_delete}">
            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
<Button Margin="5,0,20,0" cal:Message.Attach="CopyThruster($dataContext)" ToolTip="Copy">
    <Button.Content>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource appbar_page_copy}">
            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>


<Canvas x:Key="appbar_delete" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
  <Path Width="27.7083" Height="35.625" Canvas.Left="24.1458" Canvas.Top="19.7917" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 25.3333,23.75L 50.6667,23.75C 51.5411,23.75 51.8541,27.3125 51.8541,27.3125L 24.1458,27.3125C 24.1458,27.3125 24.4589,23.75 25.3333,23.75 Z M 35.625,19.7917L 40.375,19.7917C 40.8122,19.7917 41.9583,20.9378 41.9583,21.375C 41.9583,21.8122 40.8122,22.9584 40.375,22.9584L 35.625,22.9584C 35.1878,22.9584 34.0416,21.8122 34.0416,21.375C 34.0416,20.9378 35.1878,19.7917 35.625,19.7917 Z M 27.7083,28.5L 48.2916,28.5C 49.1661,28.5 49.875,29.2089 49.875,30.0834L 48.2916,53.8334C 48.2916,54.7078 47.5828,55.4167 46.7083,55.4167L 29.2917,55.4167C 28.4172,55.4167 27.7083,54.7078 27.7083,53.8334L 26.125,30.0834C 26.125,29.2089 26.8339,28.5 27.7083,28.5 Z M 30.0833,31.6667L 30.4792,52.25L 33.25,52.25L 32.8542,31.6667L 30.0833,31.6667 Z M 36.4167,31.6667L 36.4167,52.25L 39.5833,52.25L 39.5833,31.6667L 36.4167,31.6667 Z M 43.1458,31.6667L 42.75,52.25L 45.5208,52.25L 45.9167,31.6667L 43.1458,31.6667 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

For some odd reason when i run my program and click on the copy button previous buttons will lose their content, which is a canvas image. What makes things even more irritating, is that it renders just fine in the designer.

Does this buggy behavior ring a bell to anyone?

Source code available here:
[GitHub project](https://github.com/taori/SE-Calculator/commit/9a168ba34b9b422626f054a838ae69a0fa3df1e5) / [specific file](https://github.com/taori/SE-Calculator/blob/9a168ba34b9b422626f054a838ae69a0fa3df1e5/src/SE-Calculator/Presentation/Views/Sections/NewShipView.xaml)

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but shouldn't it be `$DataContext`, with capital "D"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using Icons made with a canvas. The solution to my problem was adding x:Shared="False" to my Canvas.

Eg.

```
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_delete" x:Shared="False" .../>
```

Hope that that will fix it. Just out of curiosity, for what are you going to use your program? Looks interesting...

Regards
SanHolo

Comment: yup! that fixed it. thanks. It's for a game i'm playing. Since there is no built in information i made a little program to calculate things for me to get an idea of whether my ship can even take off :)